# Beginner Python - How to modify a list using a function

Tags: python, list, function

I'm teaching myself Python out of a book and I am having trouble with the 2nd part of this 2 part exercise.

**The 1st part of the exercise:**
*Make a list of magician’s names. Pass the list to a function called show_magicians(), which prints the name of each magician in the list.*

I was able to do this part with no problem

**My code for the 1st part:**

```
magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

def show_magicians():
    for name in magicians_names:
        print(name)


show_magicians()
```

**The 2nd part of the exercise:**
*Start with a copy of your program from Exercise 8-9. Write a function called make_great() that modifies the list of magicians by add- ing the phrase the Great to each magician’s name. Call show_magicians() to see that the list has actually been modified.*

**My code for the 2nd part**

```
magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

def show_magicians():
    for name in magicians_names:
        print(name)

def make_great():


show_magicians()
```

I've tried just about every idea I can think of for the make_great function but nothing has worked so far. Any ideas or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far for your `make_great` method?

Comment: You didn't do part 1 correctly yet. Maybe doing it the right way will help: The exercise tells you to *pass* the list. You're currently just accessing the list `magicians_names` that's defined globally.

Comment: And just a little extra detail, I think your `show_musicians` is supposed to be called `show_magicians `

Comment: @Shawn hmmm ok let me think about that

Comment: @idjaw good looking out...just making sure you're paying attention lol

Answer (score 1):

Each item in a list has an associated index, starting from zero.  As you probably know, you can access the items in the list using those indexes:

```
>>> magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']
>>> magicians_names[0]
'Marv'
```

You can also modify the list items using those indexes:

```
>>> magicians_names[0] = 'Jerry Boomfang'
>>> magicians_names[0]
'Jerry Boomfang'
```

So what you need to do is loop through both the list and its indexes, modifying as you go.  Which is exactly what the enumerate function is for.

```
>>> for index, magician in enumerate(magicians_names):
...     magicians_names[index] += ' is great!'
...
>>> magicians_names
['Jerry Boomfang is great!', 'Wowzo is great!', 'Trickster is great!', 'Didlo is great!']
```

Comment: Thanks james appreciate the answer. However this method is getting into things the book has yet to cover so I don't think this is the way I'm supposed to go about it even though it does produce the desired output

Comment: Maybe the book thinks you should create a counter, set it to 0, step through the list using the counter as your list index and increment it as you go.  But that's not the best way to do it in Python.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure it involves that either because the book hasn't covered anything regarding that yet. I have noticed that beginner books tend to give examples that aren't exactly the most efficient for the sake of teaching a particular concept and later build on those concepts to show how you can achieve the same thing more efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. The `[:]` retains the original list by making a copy or slice of the the original list to be used in the function being called. The exercises in the book are 8-9 to 8-11 on page 150 *Crash course in Python*.

```
def meta_mags(show_mags, great_mags):
    """(Change regular show magicians to Great magicians by moving them 
     to another list using a function meta_mags)"""
    while show_mags:
        change_mags = show_mags.pop()
        # show the change from one list show_mags to great_mags
        print("Great magicians: " + change_mags.title())
        great_mags.append(change_mags)


def show_great_mags(great_mags):
    """Print --The Great--- after each great_mags magicians name"""
    for great_mag in great_mags:
        print(great_mag.title() +" The Great will be performing tonight !") 


show_mags = ['alice', 'david', 'carolina']
great_mags = []
meta_mags(show_mags[:], great_mags)
show_great_mags(great_mags) 
print(show_mags)
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Simplest (although not so pretty) solution, with `range` and `len`:

```
def make_great():
    for i in range(len(magicians_names)):
        magicians_names[i] = 'The Great ' + magicians_names[i] + ' !'
```

---

**ACTUAL ANSWER**

There are multiple solutions to this, I see two that are quite easy :

1. Run through the indexes of your list, that is to say a [`range`](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) of the same length as `magicians_names`.

   - You can access element number `i` in a list `lst` with `lst[i]`
   - `range(n)` generates a list : `[0, 1, 2, ..., n-1]`
   - [`len`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_len.htm) is a function that gives the length of a list (or the length of many things, but what we're interested in are lists)

This gives :

```
def make_great():
    # len(magician_names) is 4, and range(4) is [0, 1, 2, 3]
    for i in range(len(magicians_names)):
        # update the content of the list like this
        magicians_names[i] = 'The Great ' + magicians_names[i] + ' !'
```

2. Another way is to use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, which will provide a tuple like `(index, element)` for each element of your list.

Like this :

```
def make_great():
    # enumerate(magician_names) is [(0, 'Marv'), (1, 'Wowzo'), ...]
    for i, name in enumerate(magicians_names):
        # update the content of the list like this
        magicians_names[i] = 'The Great ' + name + ' !'
```

The second way is considered a bit more elegant, although both of them work. To test it, run `make_great()` first, to modify the list. Then run `show_magicians()`

```
>>> make_great()
>>> show_magicians()
The Great Marv !
The Great Wowzo !
The Great Trickster !
The Great Didlo !
```

---

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

This actually modifies the list `magicians_names`, and you may not want this in the future. You could run the function over a copy of your list. To create a copy of the list, you can use `[:]`, which means *all the elements from*.

```
copy_of_mn = magicians_names  # does not copy : if you modify one, you modify the other
copy_of_mn = magicians_names[:]  # does copy : the two are the sames, but independent
```

If you want to obtain this list, you could do it this way (creating a copy and modifying it), or with `append` to an empty list.

```
def make_great():
    # create an empty list
    result = []
    # we don't even need 'enumerate' anymore
    for name in magicians_names:
        # 'this.append(that)' means 'add that at the end of this'
        result.append('The Great ' + name + ' !')
    # return the list (if you omit this line, the function will return 'None')
    return result
```

With this solution, the function returns a list with all the modified names : `['The Great Marv !', 'The Great Wowzo !', 'The Great Trickster !', 'The Great Didlo !']`

A small modification of `show_magicians` later, you can print them !

```
def show_magicians(list_of_names):
    for name in list_of_names:
        print(name)
```

And then just call `show_names(make_great(magicians_names))`, as `make_great(magicians_names)` will create a list of all the modified names, and `show_names(something)` prints all the elements of `something`.

You might also want to be able to reuse your method with other lists, and other things to add. The idea is to use parameters for your functions, as introduced in the last piece of code :

```
def add_prefix_and_suffix(list_of_names, prefix, suffix):
    for i, name in enumerate(list_of_names):
        # alter the list_of_names, adding prefix and suffix to the name
        list_of_names[i] = prefix + name + suffix
```

Then you could simply use `add_prefix_and_suffix(magicians_names, 'The Great ', ' !')` instead of `make_great`. And even more, you could define `make_great` from this function !

Beginner way :

```
def make_great():
    add_prefix_and_suffix(magicians_names, 'The Great ', ' !')
```

[Lambda](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) way :

```
make_great = lambda: add_prefix_and_suffix(magicians_names, 'The Great ', ' !')
```

There are many things that can be done from your exercise, but I think this is enough for now. I've provided some links as an example, but you'll find many others on the Internet if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This question comes from p.150 of the Python Crash Course book.  There are several ways to do it but I think they want you to use Return, which was covered on p.142:

```
def make_great(magician_names):
    current_name = []
    for name in magician_names:
        current_name.append("The Great " + name.title())
    return current_name

magician_names = ['merlin', 'gandalf',  'saruman']

great_magician = make_great(magician_names)
print(great_magician)
```

Answer (score -1):

Redundant code, still it doesn't use enumerate -- which is much cleaner by the way.

```
magicians_names = ['Marv', 'Wowzo', 'Trickster', 'Didlo']

for m in magicians_names:
   magicians_names[magicians_names.index(m)] = "Great "+m

magicians_names
>> ['Great Marv', 'Great Wowzo', 'Great Trickster', 'Great Didlo']
```

Comment: And because you drop `enumerate`, complexity is now O(n^2), not O(n) (assuming merging strings is O(n), which is in CPython implementation)

Comment: Yes off-course.. I was thinking the exercise would be to familiarize list usage than performance analysis.